# Modify SCCM Application Deployment using Powershell fails

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm trying to process a lot of applications, wanting to add a new rule to the deployments.   Looking online, it seems folk have had success copying a rule from one application to another.   I created a template application, and a template deployment, with my template rules.

The following script is a barely modified sample of what other have used.

```
$SourceRuleName = "*"
$SourceApplicationName = "Template1"
$SourceDeploymentType = "Template DeploymentType"

$DestApplicationName = "Template2"
$DestDeploymentTypeIndex = 0

# get the applications
$SourceApplication = Get-CMApplication -Name $SourceApplicationName | ConvertTo-CMApplication
$DestApplication = Get-CMApplication -Name $DestApplicationName | ConvertTo-CMApplication

# get requirement rules from source application
$Requirements = $SourceApplication.DeploymentTypes[0].Requirements | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $RuleName}

# apply requirement rules
$Requirements | ForEach-Object {

    $RuleExists = $DestApplication.DeploymentTypes[$DestDeploymentTypeIndex].Requirements | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $RuleName}
    if($RuleExists) {

        Write-Warning "The rule `"$($_.Name)`" already exists in target application deployment type"

    } else{

        Write-Host "Apply rule `"$($_.Name)`" on target application deployment type"

        # create new rule ID
        $_.RuleID = "Rule_$( [guid]::NewGuid())"
        $DestApplication.DeploymentTypes[$DestDeploymentTypeIndex].Requirements.Add($_)
    }
}

# push changes
if($DestApplication.IsChanged){
    $Application = $DestApplication | ConvertFrom-CMApplication  
    $Application.Put()
}
```

Seems pretty straight forward, but it fails with the following error.

```
Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "The SMS Provider reported an error."
At line:37 char:5
+     $Application.Put()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Interestingly, I can get the application, and put it, if I don't add the new requirement rule.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think even if done via powershell you should be able to see a more detailed error in smsprov.log on the site server. Maybe this can help you get more insight into the problem

Answer (score 0):

How complex are the rules that you are trying to set? If it's just the one rule, have you attempted to set this via the AddRequirement parameter?:

```
Set-CMDeploymentType -ApplicationName $AppName -DeploymentName $DeploymentName -AddRequirement <rule>
```

Get that working on the template then look to integrate it into an array.

Comment: I have tried AddRequirement, but cannot find any documentation on the rule element.   That pretty much why I tried to copy a rule. The rule I need us simply to constrain certain OS versions.

Comment: I don't think there's any MS documentation out there for this. You might have come across this already, but it shows how to create the CM object for the requirements. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Add-a-Requirement-to-an-ce60681f

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be clearer to post another answer. I've basically ran through what was mentioned in the link I put in the comment and had success adding a W10 requirement to a pre-existing deployment. Here's the code I used:

```
.\Add-CMDeploymentTypeGlobalCondition.ps1 -ApplicationName $AppName -DeploymentTypeName $DeploymentName -sdkserver <servername> -sitecode <sitecode> -GlobalCondition "OperatingSystem" -Operator "OneOf" -Value "Windows/All_x64_Windows_10_Client"
```

Answer (score 0):

This Script in the Original post help
with the error the user received - this could be caused if someone has the Application open in SCCM.

"$DestDeploymentTypeIndex = 0" also needs to be increased by +1 if there is more than one deployment type.